# Browserify for using node modules in website

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, browserify

I am trying to use browserify, and I installed it using the command **npm install -g browserify**. And now I am not sure how to include it on the website. Because if I include the **index.js** it still throws error because of the requires used in index file.
I would be very grateful if someone can explain me how it works.

```html
<script src="js/browserify/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions/getdata.js"></script>
```

I tried to use requireJS too, but after I require what I need, It still says that what I require is not a function even if it is.

Comment: Did you install it like that? Or as `npm install -g browserify`?

Comment: Yes @AnanthRao, and then I copied to the folder of the website

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. `npm install -g browserify` installs the module globally, and then to use it, you have to use `browserify <fullpathofsourcefile> -o <pathofoutputfile>`

Comment: browserify doesn't allow you to link in the same file that you were using before and resolve all the requires for you, instead what it does is produce an output file with all of the required dependencies resolved and added in. So rather than including the same **index.js** file, you need to specify an output file for browserify to output to, and then include that output file instead.

Comment: @AnanthRao when I use the browserify command it says that the file from <strong>require</strong> could not be found. But it is in the same folde with the input file in browserify...

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code then. There's either something you're not requiring properly or you're not using browserify properly, but either way there's just not enough info in your question

Comment: Ok, I will include it in about an hour, because I am not at the PC right now, and I will tag you. Thanks alot!

Comment: @AnanthRao I don't need this anymore. I found I way easier way for what I need using php. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of browserify is wrong here.

You have to provide an output destination to browserify , and include that output file in your script tags, not the browserify/index.js file.

`browserify index.js > bundle.js`

Include this bundle.js in your html.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume your project folder structure  is like this below

- src/
  index.js
  index.html
- dist/
  bundle.js
- package.json
- node_modules

from your root directory run

```
browserify ./src/index.js > ./dist/bundle.js
```

this will bundle your index.js page and save it to the file you created in the dist folder as "bundle.js"

to add to your html add the script tag but instead of the index.js replace it with bundle.js

like this

this should work. I'm currently having some bundling related issues as well but this i think i can help with. cheers